# R CMD BATCH script.R ,execution via fabric run() never exits

Tags: python, r, fabric

I have written a fabric script with boto to install a R application on AWS instance. Fedora 23

All the commands using run & sudo function go as expected,

except this one:

```
@parallel
def install_DvD():
#       with settings(hide('warnings', 'running', 'stdout', 'stderr'), warn_only=True):
             cmd0 = 'R CMD BATCH %s/DvDdependencies.R' % (DvDpackage_location)
             run(cmd0)
```

As you would noticed, I tried using 'warn_only=true', and that did not help. The installation completes successfully with out errors, I check that manually by logging into the instance and eyeballing *DvDdependencies.Rout* file.
I think for reasons unkonwn to me the R CMD BATCH command does not return the execution back to fabric.

The traceback output from Ctrl^c the fabric process on my local system is:

```
[ec2-54-172-154-181.compute-1.amazonaws.com] run: R CMD BATCH ~/DvDdependencies.R
[ec2-54-165-109-62.compute-1.amazonaws.com] run: R CMD BATCH ~/DvDdependencies.R


^C
Stopped.
!!! Parallel execution exception under host u'ec2-54-165-109-62.compute-1.amazonaws.com':
!!! Parallel execution exception under host u'ec2-54-172-154-181.compute-1.amazonaws.com':
Process ec2-54-172-154-181.compute-1.amazonaws.com:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
Process ec2-54-165-109-62.compute-1.amazonaws.com:
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/eyebell/local_bin/healX/DvD-installation/py2fabvirt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fabric/tasks.py", line 242, in inner
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    submit(task.run(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/home/eyebell/local_bin/healX/DvD-installation/py2fabvirt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fabric/tasks.py", line 174, in run
    return self.wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/eyebell/local_bin/healX/DvD-installation/py2fabvirt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fabric/decorators.py", line 181, in inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/eyebell/local_bin/healX/DvD-installation/py2fabvirt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fabric/tasks.py", line 242, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/eyebell/local_bin/healX/DvD-installation/fabfile.py", line 70, in install_DvD
    run(cmd0)
  File "/home/eyebell/local_bin/healX/DvD-installation/py2fabvirt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fabric/network.py", line 649, in host_prompting_wrapper
    submit(task.run(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/home/eyebell/local_bin/healX/DvD-installation/py2fabvirt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fabric/tasks.py", line 174, in run
    return self.wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/eyebell/local_bin/healX/DvD-installation/py2fabvirt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fabric/decorators.py", line 181, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/eyebell/local_bin/healX/DvD-installation/py2fabvirt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fabric/operations.py", line 1056, in run
  File "/home/eyebell/local_bin/healX/DvD-installation/fabfile.py", line 70, in install_DvD
    run(cmd0)
  File "/home/eyebell/local_bin/healX/DvD-installation/py2fabvirt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fabric/network.py", line 649, in host_prompting_wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/eyebell/local_bin/healX/DvD-installation/py2fabvirt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fabric/operations.py", line 1056, in run
    shell_escape=shell_escape)
  File "/home/eyebell/local_bin/healX/DvD-installation/py2fabvirt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fabric/operations.py", line 925, in _run_command
    stderr=stderr, timeout=timeout)
  File "/home/eyebell/local_bin/healX/DvD-installation/py2fabvirt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fabric/operations.py", line 811, in _execute
    time.sleep(ssh.io_sleep)
KeyboardInterrupt
    shell_escape=shell_escape)
  File "/home/eyebell/local_bin/healX/DvD-installation/py2fabvirt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fabric/operations.py", line 925, in _run_command
    stderr=stderr, timeout=timeout)
  File "/home/eyebell/local_bin/healX/DvD-installation/py2fabvirt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fabric/operations.py", line 811, in _execute
    time.sleep(ssh.io_sleep)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

The complete script is here in my [github repo](https://github.com/gprakhar/DvD-installation), 
the location of [DvDdependencies.R](http://www.ebi.ac.uk/saezrodriguez/DVD/data/DvDdependencies.R) (the script that I want to install)

Any comments, help or pointers in right direction are appreciated.

Comment: So when you run `R CMD BATCH <path>/DvDdependencies.R` manually, you get prompt back, but through fabric you dont? ... interesting

Comment: Yes tested that command manually it works and exits.
In addition to that I have $R CMD INSTALL package.tar.gz commands, they too work without any issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am closing this, as the issue is with this script only.
Also the installation method for DvD tool has been updated,
hence this is not of interest anymore.